# Why it only reads the first row?

Tags: php, html

i'm trying to use if condition in a href. my problem is why it only reads the first row in database. I've also tried to use while. Here is my code...

```
<?php
  include 'dbconfig/config.php';
  $select = "SELECT * FROM schedule_tbl";
  $select_result = mysqli_query($con, $select);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($select_result)> 0) {
      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_result);
      if($row['status'] == "close") { ?>
          <li><a href="sorry.php">Enroll Now Here!</a></li>
      <?php } else { ?>
          <li><a href="enrollment.php">Enroll Now Here!</a></li>
      <?php }
  } 
?>
```

schedule.tbl

[image: schedule.tbl]

Using a `while` loop...

[image: example]

Comment: You have nothing **iterating** the results. Try `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_result)) { ... }`. You also won't need the `if(mysqli_num_rows($select_result)> 0)`

Comment: i've tried phil but it display 3 "Enroll No here!" href.

Comment: If you've tried it, put it in your question

Comment: @Keyben `mysqli_fetch_assoc` will only fetch **one** row or **null** if there are no more rows to fetch. Since you are only calling `mysqli_fetch_assoc` once, you will only have the first `$row`. Take a look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) and try again :)

Comment: @Keyben can you please update your question with **exactly** what you want to see. Also show what data you have in your `schedule_tbl` table.

Comment: i insert a image phil.

Comment: Your code displays an `<a>` tag with _"Enroll Now Here!"_ text no matter what `status` is, it just changes the `href`. I'll ask again... what exactly do you **want** to see?

Comment: He should display the title in the <a>Title</a> instead of putting any text.. If he display "Enroll Now Here"<< how did he/or other people know this Enrol Now Is belong to which title.. @Phil i also not sure what did he want to display out.. is the top navbar menu or? He should draw/draft how it should looks like

Comment: what i'm trying to see that if the status is open the enrollment view will display if not, sorry view will display... So i input 3 data in database but when i tried to change the status of second row. it displays the sorry view, suppose to display enrollment view

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($select_result) > 0)
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_result))
    {
        if ($row['status'] == "close")
        {
            //
        }
        else
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The num-rows check is completely redundant

Comment: it display 3 "Enroll now here!" in html

Comment: display 3 row? seem there are 3 rows of data that have status='closed'?

Comment: i mean in html. it echo or display "Enroll now here! "Enroll now here! "Enroll now here!"